# Copy jars place in webapp/WEB-INF/lib to war under WEB-INF/lib using maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have added a dependency under webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ folder.

When i build using maven i want to copy it in the war at WEB-INF/lib instead of WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/lib. I am looking for this to be done using maven itself.

I have mentioned packaging as war in pom file.Still the dependencies are not being copied. Am i missing something in the pom file.
I have copied the pom below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>****</groupId>
    <artifactId>*****</artifactId>
    <name>****</name>
    <description>*****</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>****</groupId>
        <artifactId>***</artifactId>
        <version>17.6</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <jbpm.version>6.3.0.Final</jbpm.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
            <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Assets.CKAF.Bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>csf-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
            <artifactId>fst</artifactId>
            <version>2.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jboss6</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Attaching screenshots of content of war.

[image: war home folder]
[image: WEB-INF content]

Comment: Adding dependencies into webapp/WEB-INF/lib is simply wrong. Just add the needed dependencies in your pom and using packaging "war" will do all the needed things...

Comment: I have mentioned the packaging as war and removed the dependencies now. But still the lib folder is empty.

Comment: The dependencies in the pom must be kept...you have to call `mvn clean package` on plain command line afterwards take a look into the resulting war file in target folder...

Comment: Can you provide a print screen of the content of the WAR you built with Maven? And also tell us what maven goal you are using.

Comment: I have tried both mvn clean package and mvn clean install. Both dont seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POM seems fine. And since you haven't specified any "scope" to the dependencies, the default scope of "compile" gets applied which means once you do a "mvn clean install" for example, it should package all those dependencies into the "lib" folder of your war file.

The only other thing I see is you have a parent section in this POM and if you have these dependencies in the parent project and if their scope is "provided" then you wont see them under the lib folder of your war file.

Comment: Yes you were right. My parent pom was excluding jars which was affecting the packaging.So had to overide the configuration by using 'combine.self="override"'. Thanks.